# flash memory write-protected problem and bad superblock

Tags: linux, partition, flash-memory

I have problem with my flash memory. after connecting it I have `/dev/sdc`  but I don't have any `/dev/sdc#` and after mounting the flash; I get the wrong fs type and bad superblock and write-protected mode, even when I mount it in read only mode.

here is the image :
[image: myInfo]

I don't care if my data lost I just want my flash memory back, I'm using Ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: Is it possible the USB flash disk is dead? Is it smart capable? Have tried to repartition it with fdisk/parted(gparted)?

Comment: in gparted it not even recongnized but in parted(commandline-tool) i have a error with Partition Table: unknown... fdisk shows `/dev/sdc` connected but there is no `/dev/sdc1`

Comment: OK, if you don't care about data, then try to create new partition with fdisk. If it doesn't work, try to delete first few MBs with dd (dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=1M count=20) and then try again with fdisk/parted

Comment: the result of your command is like this :‌
dd: failed to open '/dev/sdc': Read-only file system
----
and fdisk or gprated doesn't even recognize it.  i thinks i lost my flash memory.
---
thanks by the way

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot write anything to the device then you have a problem and there is no need to care about details. If the hardware read-only switch is not activated then your reader may be damaged. Try another one.

In any case you should have a look at the kernel messages after attaching the device:

```
dmesg | tail -n 30
```

If you are missung `/dev/sdc{1,2,3}` then the device probably had a partition table which is damaged. That would explain the damaged superblock, too, because it is looked for in the wrong place.

There are tools which can find lost partitions but that makes sense only if you get the device writable again.